# C++ Remove object from vector

Tags: c++

I would like to remove an element from a vector. For example:

```
// object that is in the vector: MyClass obj;
// vector looks as so: vector<MyClass*> pVector;

pVector.remove(obj);
```

Comment: How about `pVector.pop_back()`?

Comment: @REACHUS That removes the last element unfortunately! I wish to remove the object in which I pass as an argument!

Comment: After answering this myself, it's interesting to see how many ways we can all do the same thing... :)

Comment: @REACHUS Sorry pointer, I meant the pointer I pass as an argument!

Comment: @KarlMorrison Is `obj` a pointer or an object?

Answer (score 5):

This will remove the object based purely on the pointer. Ideally, you would have comparison functions for your `MyClass` objects that *actually check the objects* to see if they are the same.

```
pVector.erase(std::remove(pVector.begin(), pVector.end(), obj), pVector.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't well-defined, but I will provide you with two answers.  I am assuming here based on your code that `obj` is **not** a pointer, which means that we are comparing an object to pointers to objects.  This requires a custom functor.

The first answer is how to remove all elements of the vector where the value of the pointed-to element is equal to `obj`.  This assumes that there is an `operator==` that can be applied to `MyClass` objects.

```
pVector.erase(std::remove_if(pVector.begin(), pVector.end(),
                             [&obj](MyClass * i) { return i && (*i == obj); }));
```

The second will remove at most one element, if it is found:

```
auto e = std::find(pVector.begin(), pVector.end(),
                   [&obj](MyClass * i) { return i && (*i == obj); });

if (e != pVector.end()) {
    pVector.erase(e);
}
```

The lambda syntax requires C++11.  If you don't have access to C++11 then you will have to build a functor by hand:

```
template <typename T>
class pointer_is_equal_to_object
{
public:
    explicit pointer_is_equal_to_object(T const &);

    bool operator()(T const *) const;

private:
    T const & value;
}

template <typename T>
pointer_is_equal_to_object<T>::pointer_is_equal_to_object(T const & v) : value(v) {}

template <typename T>
bool pointer_is_equal_to_object<T>::operator()(T const * p) const
{
    return p && (*p == value);
}
```

Then, for example, you could use:

```
pVector.erase(std::remove_if(pVector.begin(), pVector.end(),
                             pointer_is_equal_to_object<MyClass>(obj)));
```

---

Note that this complexity goes away if you stop using pointers and just use `std::vector<MyClass>`. Then your `operator==` can be applied directly and you can just do:

```
pVector.erase(std::remove(pVector.begin(), pVector.end(), obj));
```

Comment: the std::find can not accept an UnaryPredicate as third paramter but std::find_if can, the above std::find should change to std::find_if in the second answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming C++11, and that you want to remove ANY elements matching `obj`, and not the exact `obj`... but you should be able to figure it out from here either way :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom

And for fun, here's an example: http://ideone.com/6ILYvo

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<MyClass*> v;
MyClass * toberemoved = new MyClass();

//v gets populated...

auto itr = std::remove_if(v.begin(),v.end(), [&](MyClass* a){return *a == *toberemoved;});

v.erase(itr,v.end());
```

Comment: would this also be possible with objects that have a property which I want to evaluate?