# Remove object pointer from a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I know this post can be a duplicate but the answers I could find aren't clear.

```
std::vector<EWindow> windows;
void closeWindow(EWindow* window);
```

These are my functions, I would like to erase the pointer `EWindow*`  from the vector `windows`.
[C++ Remove object from vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306086/c-remove-object-from-vector) explain how to remove object but not a pointer.

Comment: You `windows` is a vector of `EWindow`, not `EWindow*`. If you want to contain pointers, use `std::vector<EWindow*> windows`. Also it's probably best to use smart pointers, either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, depending on your needs.

Comment: You could search and erase the corresponding `EWindow`, but what about those after it? All of the pointers pointing to them will be messed up...

Comment: In fact, EWindow is an object to create a window more easily (like Qt) should I use pointers, smarts pointers or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you need to use vector of pointers to remove pointer. `std::vector<EWindow*> windows;` Code to remove pointer is from vector:

Declare your vector as vector of pointers:

```
std::vector<EWindow*> windows;

//...

void closeWindow(EWindow* window)
{
    //...
    auto RemoveIt = std::find(windows.begin(),windows.end(), window);
    if ( RemoveIt != windows.end() )
    {
        windows.erase(RemoveIt);
    }
    //...
}
```

Find element in vector then erase it from vector if it is there

Comment: @Quentin sorry, fixed)) checked it on my ide on simple chars

Comment: Thx a lot but In fact, EWindow is an object to create a window more easily (like Qt) should I use pointers, smarts pointers or not?

Comment: If OP's vector is indeed a vector of instances and not pointers to instances, this will not compile.

Comment: @iRandomXx Yes you can use smart pointers instead of simple pointers. std::unique_ptr can help if there should be one instance in program, std::shared_ptr can help when there would be many pointers on one instance. They work on RAII idiom. You don't need to take care of delete pointers.