# Replace object in vector using iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

This is my object class:

```
class person
{
public:

    int id;
    Rect rect;
};
```

In main, I am iterating through vector of `persons` and when I find a match, I want to update `rect` to some new `rect` or even replace the entire new object `person`.

```
Rect mr = boundingRect(Mat(*itc));
person per;
vector <person> persons;
vector <person>::iterator i;

i = persons.begin();
while (i != persons.end()) {
    if ((mr & i->rect).area() > 0) {
        rectangle(frame, mr, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0));
        putText(frame, std::to_string(i->id).c_str(), mr.br(),
            FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255));

        replace(persons.begin(), persons.end(), i->rect, mr); // this line causes error
        break;
    } else {
      ...
    }
```

The error I am getting at the line I marked by comment is:

```
Error   C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'person' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

and also this one:

```
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

I have tried to `erase` the object and add a new one but I was still getting the same error. I have read [C++ Remove object from vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306086/c-remove-object-from-vector) but I am not sure if this is my problem and I am not using C++11 so these solutions don't work for me.

Is it something with the iterator and my `person` object when they come to comparison? I think it is but no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Can't you do `i->rect = mr;`?

Comment: I could but I also need to use `replace` or `remove` the object...and this error occurs for both...I mean there is a workaround as you suggested, but I am looking for solution how to fix it right way.

Comment: If you just want to change the `rect` member of the current `person` object inside the vector, and keep things in the same order, you don't need to do any removing or replacing. Just `i->rect = mr;` will do exactly that, because `*i` is the object in the vector, not a copy of it. If that's not what you want, please edit the post to more exactly describe what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @mrRobot I didn't downvote, but please take a look at [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1288408) Comments on downvotes are not mandatory for many reasons. It's not trollish behavior to leave no comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare an object of type `person` with an object of type `Rect` (which is what your call to `replace` implies), then you must provide an appropriate comparison operator to do so in your `Person` class, like this:

```
bool operator== (const Rect &r) const { ... }
```

Similarly, you need an assignment operator with a signature (and probable implementation) like this:

```
person& operator= (const Rect &r) { rect = r; return *this; }
```

[Simplified live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hCdB8aa4J5POD33z)

Comment: Doesn't my call to `replace` imply that I am comparing `person->rect` with `rect` ? Isn't this the same ?

Comment: No, it tries to compare `person` with `rect`, hence your difficulties, but knowing that should help you write your `operator==` function.

Comment: And if I want to `erase` object where the iterator is pointing, how do I do it? Because I have tried it and I got same error.

Comment: Please post that as a new question, showing your code.  Try and post a [MCVE].